# Filter CSV by month and create new csv with that months data

Tags: python, csv, datetime, filter

Every time there is a new month in the "call resolve time" column I'd like to have a new csv file created with that month and year. And for all lines containing that month and year to be filtered into that new csv.

Like this:

**alldata.csv**

```
Call Resolve Time   Priority    Overall Result
8/6/2015                  P4    F
5/13/2015                 P4    F
4/28/2015                 P4    P
5/13/2015                 P4    F
5/27/2015                 P4    F
```

new file **May-2015.csv** created from **alldata.csv** with 5/XX/2015 data only

```
Call Resolve Time   Priority    Overall Result
    5/13/2015                 P4    F
    5/13/2015                 P4    F
    5/27/2015                 P4    F
```

So far I have this but I'd have to create something for every year and month manually:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(r"alldata.csv"), delimiter=',') 
filtered = filter(lambda p: '5/27/15' == p[1], reader) 
csv.writer(open(r"May-2015.csv",'w'),delimiter=',').writerows(filtered)
```

Edit ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# say, reader is the reader object
# do next(reader) to skip the headings
import csv
from itertools import groupby

reader = csv.reader(open(r"alldata.csv"), delimiter=',')

def by_month (row):
    date = row[7] 
    month = int(date.split("/", 1)[0])
    return month

m_g = groupby(reader, by_month)

for month, group in m_g:
    group = list(group)
    # use a month to month_name map
    with open('{}.csv'.format(month), 'w') as fw:
        w = csv.writer(fw)
        w.writerows(group)
```

Manually add date:

```
def by_month(row):
    date = '5/9/2016'
    month = int(date.split("/", 1)[0])
    return month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following,

```
# say, reader is the reader object
# do next(reader) to skip the headings
from itertools import groupby
def by_month(row):
    date = row[0] 
    month = int(date.split("/", 1)[0])
    return month

m_g = groupby(reader, by_month)

for month, group in m_g:
    group = list(group)
    # use a month to month_name map
    with open('{}.csv'.format(month), 'w') as fw:
        w = csv.writer(fw)
        w.writerows(group)
```

Comment if something's not working.

Comment: Thanks, its giving me a "IndexError: list index out of range". I defined the reader and checked that it was pulling from the right row. At  `line 16, in <module>
    group = list(group) line 9, in by_month
    date = row[7]`

Comment: @C Panda I had shortened the sheet , on the actual one its on the 7th row. Not sure if that was the right area to change

Comment: @iOSecure print `row[7]`  inside `by_month`. If it gives `1/2/3` like `str`, my code is correct. I didn't expect an `IndexError` of all things. Just print the `row`. let's see if I messed up.

Comment: @C Panda I've edit my main post with your code and the change I put. I think this is an issue reading the row because when I changed the `date` in `by_month` to `date = 5/9/2016` it created a file named `5` and had May's data in it.

Comment: what are you getting from row?

Comment: @C Panda The issue was there was a space between each row, that caused the index error my fault . Is it possible to get the year and month? Its outputting as just the month as "1.csv 2.csv 3.csv" etc.. But its working thank you though!

Comment: @iOSecure make a map like `{1: 'Jan',..}` or better yet checkout the `datetime` module.I believe the `by_month` function will be a one liner if you exploit `datetime`.

Comment: @C Panda How would I change it to filter by year instead of month?